# How to populate 2 DropDownListFor for Strongly Typed model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlistfor

**What I need is to do is-->** Bind 2 DropDownListFor on a view with 2 different model, which I know can't be achieved as only one model can be called on a single view.

**Initial Requirement**

@Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.MobileList, new SelectList(Model.MobileList,"Value", "Text"))

@Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.CountryList, new SelectList(Model.CountryList,"Value", "Text"))

**What I did**

**Binded one of the dropdown using**

@Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.MobileList, new SelectList(Model.MobileList,"Value", "Text"))

**For the Other Used ViewBag.**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Countrylist", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Countrylist, new { id = "CountryId", @class = "form-control", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

But I need to create both the dropdown using @Html.DropDownListFor razor code.

Comment: Did you consider using a "Tuple" like this Tuple<MobileListModel,CountryListModel> as model for the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
public class Model1{
   public int MobileId {get;set;}
  public Model2 Model2{get;set;}
  public List<SelectListItem> MobileList {get;set;}
}

public class Model2{
   public int CountryId {get;set;}
  public List<SelectListItem> CountryList {get;set;}
}
```

**In view**

```
@model Model1

    @Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.MobileId,Model.MobileList, new { @class ="form-control" }))

    @Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.Model2.CountryId,Model.Model2.CountryList, new { @class ="form-control" }))
```

You can also use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(M =>  M.Model2.CountryId, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewBag.Countrylist,"Value", "Text"), new { id = "CountryId", @class = "form-control", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

Comment: I have 2 separate models. M=>M.CountryList is not available on MobileList model

Comment: what you meant by 2 separate models? `MobileList` and `CountryList` are exist in different model?

Comment: Yes, these are 2 separate models

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you want to say.@RohitKumar

Comment: @RohitKumar Yes. you can use.Like ` @Html.DropDownListFor(M =>  M.Model2.CountryId, new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Countrylist,"Value", "Text"), new { id = "CountryId", @class = "form-control", @multiple = "multiple" })`

Comment: I needed to use ViewBag data to bind it to my dropdown and implemented it with your suggestions.I just needed to call my Second Model in the First Model and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parent model as below and using it in your view:

```
public class MainModel{
  public int CountryId {get;set;}
  public int MobileValue {get;set;}
  public List<MobileList> {get;set;}
  public List<CountryList> {get;set;}
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@model MainModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.MobileValue, new SelectList(Model.MobileList,"Value", "Text"))

@Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.CountryId, new SelectList(Model.CountryList,"Value", "Text"))
```

Comment: Just wanted to check if we can't use ViewBag while using @Html.DropDownListFor as the first parameter for it is an lamda expression.

Comment: @RohitKumar can't coz it expects Model property as first param

Comment: Is there any way we can extend this method? And avoid using a MainModel?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve after you implement DropDownListFor this way? May be there is other way

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MainModel{
  public int CountryId {get;set;}
  public int MobileValue {get;set;}
  public Tuple<List<MobileList>,List<CountryList>>  {get;set;}
}
```

> Please use the tuple for multiple list if you have only one model.